# DeleteCommand in datalist, Cannot convert int to target type string

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have this code, that i found on this website

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efx1fwb6.aspx

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="Datalist1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyField="BrandID" OnDeleteCommand="DataList1_DeleteCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="BrandNameLabel" Text='<%#Eval("BrandName") %>' />
        <br/>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Delete" Text="Slet" CommandName="Delete" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

protected void DataList1_DeleteCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int id = (int) Datalist1.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex];
    SqlDataSource1.DeleteParameters["BrandID"].DefaultValue = id;
    SqlDataSource1.Delete();
}
```

I think I have made it like the website, but i get and error called "Cannot convert source type 'int' to target type 'string'"

My BrandID is and int.
Can you please help me, and show how I convert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DefaultValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.defaultvalue.aspx) is a string. You can simply do this:

```
SqlDataSource1.DeleteParameters["BrandID"].DefaultValue =
    Datalist1.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString();
```